# DIV 100% height not respected in IE

Tags: css, html

I have an old layout that uses tables and I need to make a DIV to use the entire space of a TD. The CSS works fine in Firefox but IE interprets the 100% height as the entire window and doesn't take in account the presence of other elements on the page.

A working example can be seen in this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/micahSan/JeA6m/

Firefox will see the DIV as 100% height of what's remained but IE will see it as 100% of the entire page.

How can I make IE match Firefox?

Thank you in advance for your advice.

Comment: Is there an specific version of IE that is giving you this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know wether exists more cleaner solution for this but with `IE` are still problems :-( I don't still understand why many people using `IE` so guy must still create separated `CSS` style for `IE` ... so let's back here. Problem is that `IE` don't respect `height` of `<TD>` in `<TABLE>` i think. So i created this temporary solution, add this to your `CSS` file

```
#big_cell {
    height:100%;
    height: 45% !important;

}
```

so this `height: 45% !important` is IE hack and it will be work only for IE.

---

Or instead of using the `height` attribute because of these problems you can use a `spacer`. For example a transparent small pic which you set the height you want.